# Geopy Import Error

Tags: python, importerror, geopy

I have problems in using the Geopy package.
I have installed it with pip and I'm using python 2.7.3.

Geopy is correctly installed under

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

I've tried to run a file only importing the geopy.geocoders as suggested by the Geopy's Documentation:

`from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
 geolocator = Nominatim()`

but I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "geopy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
ImportError: No module named geocoders
```

I checked the python path printing sys.path() and I think it is correct because it shows me correctly

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geopy

and

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geopy-1.10.0.dist-info

I've also tried to uninstall and reinstall geopy, also using easy_install instead of pip but nothing changed.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your module name is geopy and thus it is higher on the PYTHONPATH than your dist-packages directory. In order to fix this, rename your python file.

In order to verify this, you can run python in verbose mode (python -v) and when importing it will tell you where it is trying to import from. In your case it should tell you it's looking in geopy.pyc as opposed to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/